# Azure Active Directory(AAD) generates token with sliding expiration of 90 days by default. How to reduce the sliding expiration time for the same?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

While accessing Microsoft Graph API, using Azure Active Directory(AAD), we can generate a token with sliding expiration as 90 days as default value.
How can we reduce the sliding expiration for the same to like 1 hr so that it can be tested.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming when you say sliding expiration, you mean refresh token which expires after 90 days by default.

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-lifetime-policies-for-refresh-tokens-and-session-tokens), you can not set the refresh token lifetime as of January 2021.

In your case, if you are using [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview), you don't have to test this expiry because it is handled by MSAL. So you can only ensure when refresh token expires, you handle the authenticating the user again.

If you just need to test what happens when refresh token expires, you can mock the expiry of the refresh token with a behavior in you test without having to touch the token expiration configurations which also is not possible.